# JPanel on Components in Netbean's free design (GroupLayout)?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, layout-manager, grouplayout

I'm trying to create a Navigation Menu like in Mobile apps with Netbeans's free design. I created a portrait panel and make it outside the frame.

As in the below images showed when the user clicks the navigation menu button the panel comes in to the panel by changing the location, but the problem is it will be behind the components (JTable and labels).

How to solve this problem ?

## state closed

[image]

## state opened

[image]

Comment: Without seeing the relevant part of the code it's hard to tell. Most likely you have to check the Z-ordering.

Comment: *"JPanel on Components in Netbean's free design (GroupLayout)?"*  Are you *certain* that 'free design' uses `GroupLayout`?  I thought free design meant a `null` layout!  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).